# Selecting with quotes with ISNULL

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase, isnull

I am trying to build a dynamic query in sybase like:

```
SELECT @v_query = @v_query + " tech= "+ ISNULL(''''+@stat+'''',"tech")
```

When I pass `@stat` as NULL, I get `''` as output but expected output is tech which is wrong

If I pass`@stat` as `NACK`, it should return 'NACK' which works as expected

Thanks for any suggestions on how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, you probably want this:

```
SELECT @v_query = @v_query + 
                  (CASE WHEN @stat IS NULL THEN '1=1'
                        ELSE 'tech = ''' + @stat + ''''
                   END)
```

Don't use `tech = tech` as a no-op (it doesn't work for `NULL`s).  Instead, just remove the comparison.

Comment: Thank you..served my purpose

Answer (score 0):

remove the '' and retry

```
declare @SQL_TXT varchar(100)
declare @stat varchar(100)
begin
select @stat= null
SELECT @SQL_TXT=@SQL_TXT + ' tech =' + ISNULL(@stat,'tech')
print @SQL_TXT
end
print tech =tech
```

edit you can do it like this

```
declare @SQL_TXT varchar(100)
declare @stat varchar(100)
begin
select @stat= null
SELECT @SQL_TXT=@SQL_TXT + ' tech = ''' + ISNULL(@stat,'tech') +''''
print @SQL_TXT
end
```

it seems adding quotes in null function give null value , can you add quotes originally to the variable as alternative ?

```
declare @SQL_TXT varchar(100)
declare @stat varchar(100)
begin
select @stat= 'SAMPLE'

select @stat= ''''+@stat+''''
SELECT @SQL_TXT=@SQL_TXT + ' tech = ' + ISNULL(@stat,'tech') 
print @SQL_TXT
end
```

Comment: In this case null is handled correctly but on passing @stat = sample, I get output as tech = sample, but output I want is tech = 'sample'

Comment: In this case when I pass null to @stat we get output as tech = 'tech' which is not correct :( in this case output should be tech= tech

Comment: After adding quotes to variable itself, on passing null to stat I get tech=

Comment: No, it did not...Thank you for your inputs